# angular-materialize DatePicker doesn't show on Edge browser, scrolls the page down on IE and Edge

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, materialize

I'm using angular-materialize for a demo project and so far it's been pretty easy to use. However, when doing a browser compatibility test pass I found that the datepicker component doesn't work when using IE and Edge browsers. On IE it scrolls the page down when the overlay appears and it doesn't even work on Edge browser. You can see the bugs [on the angular-materialize demo page](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/) Open this link in IE or Edge.

Please refrain from answering this with a question like "Why not use Angular-Material". Although the UI is similar, there are some parts of materializecss that I prefer over Google's Angular-Material. So far, this is the only issue I've found.

Comment: I fixed it and pushed the change via a buddy.